# 12.04 and Windows 7 Dual-boot won't connect with ethernet

Tags: 12.04, ethernet

My computer is dual-booted in 12.04 and Windows 7. I was connecting to the internet with an ethernet cable on 12.04 with no problems. But when I rebooted to Windows 7 I couldn't connect with ethernet. When I switched back to 12.04 I had the same problem. Wifi on both systems works just fine. Both systems tell me to plug in an ethernet cable even when one is properly plugged in.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command

```
sudo mii-tool
```

It will show the MII status of your interface. Here are sample outputs:

```
sudo mii-tool
eth0: negotiated 1000baseT-HD flow-control, link ok 

sudo mii-tool 
no MII interfaces found
```

If you have the first output then its Ok, you can now go to the last section to reload your driver. Basically mii-tool uses the MII unit of the NIC card to auto negotiate but most of the time it fails because of the NIC card problem or cable problem. Check your cable properly if you have the second output.

If that does not solve your problem you can reload the kernel module (driver):

check the driver in use:

```
sudo lshw -C network | grep "configuration"
```

You will see the output having the drivers name:

> configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes **driver=r8169**
>   driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full

Now unload the module and load again:

```
sudo modprobe --remove r8169
sudo modprobe r8169
```

Now you might need to restart the network-manager.